# Is it possible to add a windowStyle to a process directly?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, notepad

I'm currently doing a small test program learning about placing processes within `winforms`. I've created a process (just notepad for now) which displays within the form, however I'd like to remove the border and functional buttons (close, minimise, maximise etc.)

I've added my code below, perhaps an experienced C#'er might be able to guide me with where I'm going wrong?

I've tried `WindowStyle = "None"` and `WindowStyle = 0`, neither with the desired effect.

```cs
public NotepadSetParentTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Process notepad = new Process {
        StartInfo =
        {
           FileName = "notepad.exe",
           ErrorDialog = true,
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
           UseShellExecute = false,
           WindowStyle = "None"                      
        }
    };

    notepad.Start();
    SpinWait.SpinUntil(delegate
    {
        return notepad.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero;
    });
    SetParent(notepad.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
    MoveWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 15, 15, 430, 325, true);
}
```

I'd expect this to create a border less notepad process, but this actually won't compile(due to the `WindowStyle` line).

Without the `WindowStyle` line, the program compiles fine and displays the notepad program, but with the undesirable border and buttons.

Apologies if I've written this poorly, this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Comment: WindowStyle is an enumerated type of ProcessWindowStyle and won't do what you want anyway, it does, hidden, minimised, maximised and normal

Comment: You cannot alter a Window class' styles using the Process class. `SetParent` will also disappoint you.